# How input should relate/map to label y if Keras Model.fit() is given a list of input train arrays>

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to work with a Deep learning model in two of the following scenarios, where two different inputs are given. I want to achieve following:

1. Train two models (with different weights but same architecture) with same input and concatenate the result. So in model.fit(), I am passing just the trainX value. Code is given below. It works fine.

   ```py
   def create_model(input_tensor):
       x= Conv1D(filters = 16, kernel size=6, strides = 5, kernel_initializer = "uniform", activation = "relu")(input_tensor)
       x= GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
       x = Dense(2,activation ='softmax')()
       return x

   dataframe = pd.read_csv(Filename, index_col=0)
   X= dataframe.values[:,:].astype(float)
   Y = dataframe.values[:,1]

   trainx, testx, trainy, testy = train_test_split(X,Y, test_Szie= 0.2, random_state=200, shuffle =True)

   input_shape = (33000,1)
   input_tensor = Input(input_shape)
   pred_a = create_model(input_tensor)
   pred_b = create_model(input_tensor)

   out = keras.layers.Multiply()([pred_a, pred_b]) 

   model =Model(inputs=(input_tensor), outputs=out)
   model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= 'Adam', metrics =['accuracy'])
   histroy = model.fit(trainX, trainy)
   ```
2. Train same model (with same weights) twice but with different inputs. I am confused how to pass inputs in this case. In normal cases, we have equal number of instances in both trainX and trainy data. If I pass a list like `model.fit([x_train_1, x_train_2], trainy)`, then the number of instances of combined x_train_1, x_train_2 will be double than y. How trainy corresponds to the input trainx in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The input and corresponding output of a model have shapes as X =  (batch_size, ....) , y = (batch_size,....)
In case of multiple inputs, you can define multiple input layers and feed them to your different model instances as follows

```
inp_A = Input(shape=(...))
inp_B = Input(shape=(...))

pred_A = create_model(inp_A)
pred_B = create_model(inp_B)

*** Other layers and code ****
model = Model(inputs=[inp_A, inp_B], outputs=out)
*** Other code ***
```

Then you can call model.fit with passing a list of inputs and a single output.

Comment: thanks but how does input trainx corresponds to trainy,, like if trainx has shape (10,5) and trainy has shape (10,2), then trainx  instance 1 has label at first location trainy, trainx second instance has label at trainy second location etc. right? if two inputs are given with one output label array, how they link together? or am I missing something

Comment: Can you explain the type of problem you're trying to solve? What is your target variable? If your train_x has the shape (10,5) that means there are 10 samples having 5 features each and your train_y having shape (10, 2) means that for each of those 10 examples you're trying to predict 2 values. If you want to input 2 inputs with 10 samples each and having 5 features in each sample your input shape or train_x shape would be (10, 2, 5) and your output shape or train_y would be (10, 2, label_dim) where label_dim depends on the type of target variable you're trying to predict.

Comment: you can instead, also define your input to be an array of [(10, 5), (10, 5)]and use two input layers, then your target would be of shape (10, 2) with two elements predicting the targets for your both inputs. But then your model design would be different.

Comment: It is binary classification problem, target has 2 classes, ofcourse the number of instances and number of features is huge,, but following above mentioned code with model = Model(inputs=[inp_A, inp_B], outputs=out), returns shape error (raise valueerror (shapes % s and %s are incompatible % self order, shape(1,1,1) and shape (1,1,2 )) are incompatible.

Comment: exact input shapes are trainX = (800, 842, 1) and trainy is (800,2)

Comment: That's because your model outputs a single value while you are feeding a target variable with 2 components

Comment: your train_y should be of shape (800, 1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211097/discussion-between-eshaa-and-abtexp).